# Is there a maximum number of simple Polylines on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, polyline

I am using Google Maps Javascript API v3 and the Chrome browser. I will be rendering a large number of simple (two point) Polylines on a map. Has anyone encountered any upper limit in terms of numbers of Polyines before browser performance starts to become an issue?

Comment: Well, that really depends on the Computer running the browser. Anyway, do you have an expected upper bound of polyline numbers? Also, there is a great different between browsers. Chrome is much, much faster rendering polylines than IE, for instance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Maps Javascript API v3 with large layers then Google is rendering layers for you but there is a file size limit.

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport
*When simple KML files are loaded via GGeoXml and client-side, browser-based feature rendering is chosen, GOverlay-based objects are created and added to the map, triggering addoverlay events accordingly. On the other hand, when large KML files are loaded with GGeoXml and server-side rendering is invoked, these objects are not created and addoverlay is not triggered.*

But there is [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) which uses your computer resources, not Google's.